# Take picture from IP Camera in UWP

Tags: camera, uwp, ip-camera

I'm working on a project that using IP camera to show preview and take a picture.
I found many tutorials that help we do that with USB camera but nothing with IP camera. So my question is how can we do it with IP Camera, and how does it work? Do we have any extension that helps we do it?